# How can I know if my python script is running within zipapp package?

Tags: python, zipapp

I have a python script that uses the `__file__` variable to take some action. This was working fine before I used zipapp since `__file__` matched the actual running file.

Now I am starting to use zipapp and the logic doesn't work anymore, because `__file__` is `"loinc.pyz"` and not `"loinc.py"`.

Is there a way that, within my Python code, I can tell if the file is actually loinc.pyz, say, rather than loinc.py?

The only way I can see to do it now is to just try to see if `__file__ + "z"` exists, and if it does, assume we're using zipapp. But I'd like something more elegant.

I looked at the specifications from zipapp https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html but couldn't find anything. Looked at the 8 pages of zipapp-referenced questions in Stack Overflow and nothing either.

Comment: I haven't used zipapp myself (and am not currently at a computer), but I'm confused. You say that now, with zipapp, `__file__` is `"loinc.pyz"`. Isn't that correct? Why do you have to manually add `"z"` if it's already there in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.argv[0]`.

(*Note: this example was created on a UNIX system. Command invocations on a ms-windows system will differ.*)

Create a file `__main__.py`:

```
import sys

print(f"__file__ = {__file__}")
print(f"sys.argv[0] = {sys.argv[0]}")
```

(Zipped Python executables depend on the name `__main__.py` being present in the zipfile.)

Next, create a file named `hdr`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Compress `__main__.py`:

```
zip -q foo __main__.py
```

This will create `foo.zip`.

Concatenate the header and the zipfile, and make the resulting file executable:

```
cat hdr foo.zip >foo.pyz
chmod u+x foo.pyz
```

Now, call `__main__.py`:

```
> python __main__.py 
__file__ = /zstorage/home/rsmith/tmp/src/__main__.py
sys.argv[0] = __main__.py
```

Then call `foo.pyz`:

```
> ./foo.pyz 
__file__ = /zstorage/home/rsmith/tmp/src/./foo.pyz/__main__.py
sys.argv[0] = ./foo.pyz
```

Note how `__file__` ends with `__main__.py` in both cases!